# Kendo dataviz pie chart as button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

Is it possible to use the Kendo-Dataviz pie chart as a button control. I want every piece to be a different control.

I could not find anything like that in the documentation.

Comment: Would the chart's client-side click events not give you the functionality you would need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might define a [`seriesClick`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#events-seriesClick) event. Something like:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [
        {
            type: "pie",
            categoryField: "type",
            data: [
                { value: 1, type: "Category 1" },
                { value: 2, type: "Category 2" }
            ]
        }
    ],
    seriesClick : function (e) {
        alert("You clicked on: " + JSON.stringify(e.dataItem));
    }
});
```

See it running here : http://jsfiddle.net/rS3T4/

Comment: Thank you for your answer after more digging I did eventually find the way to do this, but I must say it wasn't easy, because I started working with Kendo this morning with no prior knowledge that it even existed. XD Thanks again.

Comment: If the answer differs from this please submit it here so others can get advantage of you what you learnt. If it is this same, you might accept it and let others know that this is the way of doing it. Welcome to KendoUI world!